# IE 10 or IIS6 not working with box.shadow

Tags: html, css, iis-6, internet-explorer-10

I am having problems getting `box-shadow` to work.  I ran a very simple program that produces a `div` with `box-shadow`, it displays properly running off of XAMPP using Firefox and IE10 but when using IIS6 firefox works and IE10 does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
        div
        {
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
            background-color:yellow;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>allo</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE is probably not using IE10 mode, you can check with Developer Tools (press F12).

If not, the easiest fix is to add this inside `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```